# JQuery Datatables - Compare value with two columns value

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have 2 column with date and would like to verify if record with content  have a parallel record, here is an example:

```
-------------------
Open     |
-------------------
Open     |  Hello
-------------------
Closed   |  Closed
-------------------
Processed|  
------------------
```

The record that have the value OPEN should not have any text (word: hello -- in this case) as such a class must be applied etc

Here is my code so far, thank you a lot!

```
"rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
  if (data[1] === 'Open' && data[2].length > 0) {
    $(row).addClass('selected');
  }
}
```

Comment: The only issue I can see... Is the fact that column indexes are zero-based. It seems like you need to use `data[0]` and `data[1]` in the comparison.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette correct, however data[0] and data[1] parameters can be changed.. depending on what data that need to be compared

Answer (score 0):

here is a working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/7426/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [
    ["1", "Open", ""],
    ["2", "Open", "Hello"],
    ["3", "Closed", "Closed"],
    ["4", "Processed", ""],

  ];

  var columnDefs = [{
    title: "id"
  }, {
    title: "status"
  }, {
    title: "whatever"
  }];

  var myTable;

  myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "rowCallback": function(row, data) {
      if (data[1] == "Open" && data[2].length > 0) {
        console.log(data[2]);
        $(row).addClass('selected');
      }
    },
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columnDefs,
    dom: 'Bfrtip', // Needs button container
    select: 'single',
    responsive: true,
    altEditor: true, // Enable altEditor
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Add',
        name: 'add' // do not change name
      },
      {
        extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
        text: 'Edit',
        name: 'edit' // do not change name
      },
      {
        extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
        text: 'Delete',
        name: 'delete' // do not change name
      }
    ]
  });


});
```

Comment: interesting.. I hope the above code helps someone in the future!